# TreeView only expand few nodes

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I want to let my `tree view` only expand 5 nodes.
I use `ExpandDepth=5`, but it will only expand 5 nodes at the beginning.

Comment: You want expand 5 nodes in first level ?

Comment: no, i want to expand 5 level.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each tn As TreeNode In treeView1.Nodes
    If tn.Level = 1 or tn.Level = 2 or tn.Level = 3 or tn.Level = 4 or tn.Level = 5 Then
        tn.Expand()
    End If
Next
```

Try this code

Comment: You are checking for tn.Level = 5 twice.